# Do/While not recognizing the character to end loop in C

Tags: c, loops, file, do-while, restart

I'm trying to write some characters in this "arq.txt" file and it works well at the beginning, but when I type zero to restart the program, the Do / While loop no longer recognizes zero I can't get out of it anymore. Please help me! Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *p;
    char ch;
    int c = 1, i, cont = 0;

    while(c) {

        printf("\n-------- DIGITANDO VALORES --------\n");

        p = fopen("arq.txt", "w");
        do {
            printf("Type: ");
            scanf("%c", &ch);
            getchar();
            putc(ch, p);
            cont++;
        } while(ch != '0');
        fclose(p);

        p = fopen("arq.txt", "r");
        for(i = 0; i <= cont; i++) {
            ch = fgetc(p);
            printf("%c\n", ch);
        }
        fclose(p);

        printf("If you wish to finish program, please type zero: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using `getchar` after `scanf` to consume a newline?  That looks really weird.  What do you mean by "works well"?  It seems like you're reading every other character.

Comment: Ahhh.  Are you trying to terminate the outer while loop by typing '0'?  '0' != 0.  Change the outer loop to `while( c != '0')`

Comment: @WilliamPursell  `c` is an `int`.

Comment: Yeah! I mean... At first all the characters that I type are written to this file until I type '0'. And I can print all of them. But when I restart this program, it should work fine again, but I can't get out of do/while loop even if I type zero...

Comment: @DouglasdeBrito Why did you code `getchar();` after `scanf("%c", &ch);`?

Comment: Yes, you need to write `while ( c != '0' ) ` instead of `while(c)`.  As I said, `'0' != 0`

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica it works!!! Thanks you, guys!!! :D

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica because "enter" was being recognized as an input. That cleans the buffer, write?

Comment: DouglasdeBrito, OK, why not do the same after  `scanf("%d", &c);`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell `while ( c != 0)` is not the issue - that is OK.  `int c` is initialized with 1 and later changed with `scanf("%d", &c);`  It is not used as a character, but an `int` and a test against 0  is OK.  Testing against `'0'` would only stop the loop if user entered `"48"`.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Does it work with other types of data?

Comment: DouglasdeBrito  It depends on many things.  As suggested, use `fgets()` to read user input, then other functions to parse the string.  `scanf()` tries to both at once and does not do either job well.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the patient explanation. I was thrown by not looking closely at the format string and assumed it was `"%c"`.  I'll mark this up as yet one more datapoint to demonstrate that `scanf` should never be used!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I too was  initially thrown off and agree about  evils of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%c", &ch);` reads left-over newline from `scanf("%d", &c);`.

Try `scanf("%c", &ch); getchar();` --> `scanf(" %c", &ch);`.  Note space

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot :D
But why did it work? hahahah

Comment: @DouglasdeBrito  `scanf(" %c", &ch);`, with space, first consumes leading white-space like `'\n'`, space, tab ...  Pro tip: stop using `scanf()` until you know why it is so troublesome.  Instead research `fgets()`, `sscanf()`.

Comment: Hmmmm... I think I got it. Thanks :)